# How to automatically kill chromedriver when parent process closes?

Tags: c#, selenium, debugging, selenium-webdriver, process

Is there a way to have chromedriver.exe automatically close when my process is terminated?

Visual studio kills my process when I stop the debugger.

Since it kills the process, its not able to run the close and quit functions of IWebDriver in the window closing event.

I rather not make a secondary application that behaves like a monitoring heartbeat that kills chromedriver.exe whenever my process closes.

Comment: No. Don't stop the debugger, hit play after debugging and it will clean up normally. I just created a batch file on my desktop that I run when I know some threads weren't cleaned up. It generally isn't a problem to leave a few here and there. The only thing I've seen is that you can't Clean from VS because it can't clean up chromedriver.exe since it's still running. Running the batch file and then running Clean fixes that.

Comment: @Clint Its not.